# How can I add a button for each box that I have in my horizontal list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't find a way to add a button to each of the icons, they just show up but they don't have any type of action to navigate to another page.
Here is my code, possibly what I ask for is very easy and I apologize in advance,

If you need me to send you some other type of file I have no problem.

Widget upperPart() {

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    ClipPath(
      clipper: UpperClipper(),
      child: Container(

        height: size.getWidthPx(240),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(

            colors: [colorCurve, colorCurveSecondary],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.getWidthPx(36)),

          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              titleWidget(),

              SizedBox(height: size.getWidthPx(10)),

              upperBoxCard(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        leftAlignText(
            text: "Cercanos a ti",

            leftPadding: size.getWidthPx(16),

            textColor: textPrimaryColor,

            fontSize: 16.0),

        HorizontalList(

          children: <Widget>[

            for  (int i = 0; i < premiumList.length; i)
              propertyCard(premiumList[i],),

          ],
        ),
```

Comment: if your `premiumList` is a `List` of something then see `List.map` and `Iterable.toList` methods

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
HorizontalList(
  children: premiumList.map((item) => propertyCard(item)).toList(),
)
```

Comment: Try to implement that line and it does not take the function of button. What I need is that each instance that appears in the list has the function of having a button

Comment: I don't see the implementation of propertyCard() so I can't help you with that. It should have the button.

Comment: This is the statement you asked for

Comment: Well, it doesn't have a button.. You should add a button there..

Answer (score 0):

This is the statement you asked for

Card propertyCard(Property property) {
    return Card(

```
    elevation: 4.0,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
    borderOnForeground: true,
    child: Container(
        height: size.getWidthPx(150),
        width: size.getWidthPx(170),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(12.0)),
                child: Image.asset('assets/${property.image}',
                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
            SizedBox(height: size.getWidthPx(8)),
            leftAlignText(
                text: property.propertyName,
                leftPadding: size.getWidthPx(8),
                textColor: colorCurve,
                fontSize: 14.0),
            leftAlignText(
                text: property.propertyLocation,
                leftPadding: size.getWidthPx(8),
                textColor: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 14.0),
            SizedBox(height: size.getWidthPx(4)),
            leftAlignText(
                text: property.propertyPrice,
                leftPadding: size.getWidthPx(8),
                textColor: colorCurve,
                fontSize: 14.0,

                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
          ],

        )));
```

}